# Which is faster, C & MySql or PHP & MySql?

Tags: php, mysql, c, performance, insert

I need to perform 3 million inserts to the database (mysql). PHP seems to be slow when it comes to insertion. I just need to verify if C performs faster in executing codes.

Comment: Does it really matter? Do you need to perform those inserts frequently?

Comment: If it is a one-time thing, I would use mysqlimport / LOAD DATA INFILE.

Comment: MySql takes 15 seconds; PHP takes 0.0004; C takes 0.00002 (20 times faster than PHP) ... C & MySQL take 15.00002; PHP & MySQL take 15.0004 or just about the same time :)

Answer (score 11):

The bottleneck is probably the database regardless of programming language.

You should look into batch inserts and disabling of indexes during insert to speed up the process.

Comment: First, i need to generate data in the the script before inserting into database. So data generation runs in the PL i would use.

Comment: Well, you said that you need to insert data, you didn't talk about "generating" data. If you can benchmark the "data generation" and "SQL insert" independently, then you easily see if there are any gains by switching language.

Answer (score 0):

C is indeed faster, but I also think that database is the big bottleneck